# Sharepoint foundation 2013, claims/FBA based authentiction and SSO

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, extranet, sso

My Scenerio is this:

I have a big client that supplies services to a few partners of his.

he would like to create a sharepoint farm (hosted on a VM) for each of his clients, installed with sharepoint 2013 foundation. Each sharepoint domain and it's client domain are different.

he wants these users to authenticate using Single Sign on.

But here is the catch: because of information security no trusts can be set between the domains, and setting up ADFS for every client is not an option.

can this be achieved? and if so how? 
from what i've read i think probably claim authentication is the way to go.. but i'm not sure it can work with SSO.